# Learn to Program Ruby Chapter 11.7

Tags: ruby

I'm doing Chris Pine's Learn to Program 2nd Ed book for ruby. I can't seem to replicate his Ch 11.7 example. Would really appreciate any input. Thanks! For some reason when I run this program, it will puts the following:

What do you want to call the root name for these files?

testtext

Downloading 0 files:
Done!

The files don't move. Also, the folder structure is as follows

```
+-- _6write
|   +-- copyfiles
|   |   +-- New Text Document.txt
|   |   +-- New Text Document - Copy.txt
|   |   +-- New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
|   +-- pastefiles
```

Below is the code:

```
#Ch 11.7 Example

Dir.chdir 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\RoR\Ruby Projects\_6write\pastefiles' 
pic_names = Dir['C:\Users\user\Desktop\RoR\Ruby 
Projects\_6write\copyfiles\*.{txt, TXT}']

puts "What do you want to call the root name for these files?" batch_name = 
gets.chomp puts print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} files: "

pic_number = 1

pic_names.each do |name|   print '.'

  new_name = if pic_number <10
    "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"   else
    "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"   end   File.rename name, new_name

  pic_number = pic_number + 1 end

puts

puts "Done!"
```

Comment: is the missing linefeed after the `"What do you want to call.."` also in your code?

Comment: Is there a linefeed in the path before `Project`? I'm not sure, but I think there shouldn't be a space between `{txt, TXT}`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get multiple `SyntaxErrors` when I try your code. The output you are posting cannot possibly be generated by the code you posted. Please, make sure that the code you posted *accurately* reflects your problem. Also, it would help if you could change the title of your question. The title of your question should tell the reader whether or not it is worthwhile for them to read the full text; i.e. it should describe what the problem is you are having, so that I can know whether or not I can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

Dir.chdir 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\RoR\Ruby Projects_6write\pastefiles' 
pic_names = Dir['C:\Users\user\Desktop\RoR\Ruby']

it has to be

Dir.chdir 'C:/Users/dlma1/Desktop/RoR/Ruby Projects/_6write/pastefiles'
pic_names = Dir['C:/Users/dlma1/Desktop/RoR/Ruby Projects/_6write/copyfiles/*.{txt,TXT}']

So / must be used instead of \ when using Dir in the yaml module.